# I want to create a custom checkered pattern effect with a shader in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want to create a customizable checkboard pattern in unity, based on a 3 x 3 int grid, in which i specify with a 1 which pixel is transparent and with 0 a full color one.

The problem is that so far i cant find any type of struct to hold said matrix. I tried a mat3x3, int3x3, and float3x3, but after i initialize them in the pass, they return the same value on all indexes, namely 0.

v2f.muv contains screen position coordinates

Am i initializing it wrong?

```
const int3x3 c8 = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                    col.a = c8[ i.muv.x % 3 ][ i.muv.y % 3 ];
                    return col;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after messing another 5 mins after posting, i found out i just had to put static in front of the initialization.